# Azure B2C Custom Policy Precondition not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I have a simple Precondition during ValidationTechnicalProfile, that compares claim with a string, I want to Skip that validation step if value matches but it doesn't executes even though the Value is correct:

```
<Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>myClaim</Value>
                  <Value>SomeStringValue</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
```

When I see b2c-logs I do see **myClaim** value set to **SomeStringValue** but it doesn't executes the Action. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem. You haven't shown all the code but have a look at [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/issues-with-an-azure-ad-b2c-self-asserted-page-calling-a-validationtechnicalprofile-decb47c99d34). That may be the problem i.e.

"myClaim has to be an output claim in the self-asserted TP that calls this validation TP!"